# 2 errors Could not acquire lock for index: when reindexing

Tags: magento2, reindex

When I reindex a Magento 2.4.4-p2 webshop, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Category Products index process error during indexation process:
Could not acquire lock for index: catalog_category_product
Product Categories index process error during indexation process:
Could not acquire lock for index: catalog_product_category
```

- I have reset the indexes
- I checked the file permissions
- There are no hanging cron jobs

Anyone have an idea what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the post, "**reset the index and no hanging cron**" suspecting issue on any attributes creation/updation went wrong or saved **store-view** may be wrong. 
 
Please try with disable crons and enter maintenance mode.

UPDATE **mview_state** SET version_id = '0'; in order to reset all statusses and versions to their starting position. In my case they did not increment anymore and index_all_invalid gave the lock error. 
Then truncate cron_schedule 
After this,reindex from cli, clear cache, disable maintenance and re-enable crons.

 
Hope it works for you or points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are experiencing issues with the Magento indexing process. The error message "Could not acquire lock for index" indicates that the index process is currently locked and cannot be accessed or updated.

There are a few possible reasons for this error:

Another indexing process is currently running: When you reindex a Magento store, the indexing process can take some time to complete, especially if you have a large number of products and categories. If another indexing process is already running, it may cause the error message you are seeing.

There is a problem with the database: If there are issues with the Magento database, it could cause problems with the indexing process. This could include issues with database connectivity, permissions, or other problems.

The indexing process has been manually locked: It's possible that the indexing process has been manually locked by an administrator or developer in order to perform some maintenance or troubleshooting.

To fix this issue, you can try the following steps:

Wait for the current indexing process to complete: If another indexing process is currently running, you may need to wait for it to finish before you can reindex your store.

Check the Magento logs for errors: The Magento logs can provide more information about the cause of the indexing error. You can check the logs by going to System > Tools > Logs in the Magento admin panel.

Check the database connectivity and permissions: Make sure that the Magento database is properly configured and that the user account used to connect to the database has the necessary permissions.

Unlock the indexing process: If the indexing process has been manually locked, you will need to unlock it in order to reindex your store. You can do this by going to System > Index Management in the Magento admin panel and clicking the "Unlock" button next to the affected index.

I hope this information helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go into maintenance mode or do database updates.
Just run:

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```