# Could not acquire lock for index: catalog_category_product

Tags: magento2.4.5, reindexing

after upgrade from M2.3 to 2.4.5, I removed cron and enabled maintenance mode,Truncate cron_schedule table, mview_state version id is 0 but when i try to re-index it gives errors `Could not get lock for index: catalog_category_product`
Please help me i dont understand why reindexing didn't work

Answer (score 0):

A similar question already exists and has been answered: [2 errors Could not acquire lock for index: when reindexing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363006/2-errors-could-not-acquire-lock-for-index-when-reindexing)

Since you've already set mview_status to 0 focus on the second answer. If that doesn't solve your issue please update your question with additional context including the steps you tried to resolve the issue and the outcomes including any relevant logs or screenshots.

Good luck!